# validate multiple json values in play

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have the following json fields coming from the request

```
Action {
  request =>
    val jsValueOption = request.body.asJson
    jsValueOption.map {
      json =>
          val f1 = (json \ "f1").validate[String]
          val f2 = (json \ "f2").validate[String]
          val f3 = (json \ "f3").validate[String]
    ...
```

And I need to make sure all of these fields are present in order to continue. Otherwise, throw an `BadRequest` response. What is the proper way of doing this? Do I use `get` on these `JsResult` and then use `try-catch` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comprehension part of answer removed because, as @kipsigman pointed out, `map`/`flatMap` for `JsResult` do not behave like the applicative and accumulate failures. I knew this too. Insert Tony Morris saying, "told you so".

I wouldn't access the body directly like this anyways and would instead define `Reads`/`Format` either via macro like below, or via the applicative combinators like @kipsigman.

```
case class MyRequest(f1: String, f2: String, f3: String)
object MyRequest { implicit val reads: Reads[MyRequest] = Json.reads[MyRequest] }

Action.async(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[MyRequest].map {
    myRequest => 
      JsString(s"f1 is '${myRequest.f1}' f2 is '${myRequest.f2}' f3 is '${myRequest.f3}'")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would approach it (based off the 2.3 snapshot documentation - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3-SNAPSHOT/ScalaJsonHttp). Very similar to drstevens, but I used a fold on the validation result to demonstrate the BadRequest/OK flow. It's also worth noting the the Reads pattern I used will give you an accumulation of validation errors for all fields.

```
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class MyRequest(f1: String, f2: String, f3: String)
implicit val myRequestReads: Reads[MyRequest] = (
  (JsPath \ "f1").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "f2").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "f3").read[String]
)(MyRequest.apply _)

def myAction = Action(BodyParsers.parse.json) { request =>
  val jsResult = request.body.validate[MyRequest]
  jsResult.fold(
    errors => {
      BadRequest(Json.obj("status" ->"KO", "message" -> JsError.toFlatJson(errors)))
    },
    myRequest => {
      println("Successful Request, f1 = " + myRequest.f1)
      Ok(Json.obj("status" ->"OK")
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: +1 for accumulating. They should remove `flatMap` for `JsResult`,`Reads`, etc and all references to "Monadic" in their documentation.